# Extracting specific information from fetched HTML code using python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm a relatively newb in python. I need some advice for a bioinformatics project. It's about converting certain enzyme IDs to others.

What I already did and what works, is fetch the html code for a list of IDs from the Rhea database:

```
 53 url2 = "http://www.rhea-db.org/reaction?id=16952"
 54 f_xml2 = open("xml_tempfile2.txt", "w")
 55
 56 fetch2 = pycurl.Curl()
 57 fetch2.setopt(fetch2.URL, url2)
 58 fetch2.setopt(fetch.WRITEDATA, f_xml2)
 59 fetch2.perform()
 60 fetch2.close
```

So the HTML code is saved to a temporary txt file (I know, possibly not the most elegant way to do stuff, but it works for me ;).

Now what I am interested in is the following part from the HTML:

```
        <p>
            <h3>Same participants, different directions</h3>
            <div>
                <a href="./reaction?id=16949"><span>RHEA:16949</span></a>
                <span class="icon-question">myo-inositol + NAD(+) &lt;?&gt; scyllo-inosose + H(+) + NADH</span>
            </div><div>
                <a href="./reaction?id=16950"><span>RHEA:16950</span></a>
                <span class="icon-arrow-right">myo-inositol + NAD(+) =&gt; scyllo-inosose + H(+) + NADH</span>
            </div><div>
                <a href="./reaction?id=16951"><span>RHEA:16951</span></a>
                <span class="icon-arrow-left-1">scyllo-inosose + H(+) + NADH =&gt; myo-inositol + NAD(+)</span>
            </div>
        </p>
```

I want to go through the code until the class "icon-arrow-right" is reached (this expression is unique in the HTML). Then I want to extract the information of "RHEA:XXXXXX" from the line above. So in this example, I want to end up with 16950.

Is there a simple way to do this? I've already experimented with HTMLparser but couldn't get it to work in a way that it looks for a certain class and then gives me the ID from the line above.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to do this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """ <p>
...             <h3>Same participants, different directions</h3>
...             <div>
...                 <a href="./reaction?id=16949"><span>RHEA:16949</span></a>
...                 <span class="icon-question">myo-inositol + NAD(+) &lt;?&gt; scyllo-inosose + H(+) + NADH</span>
...             </div><div>
...                 <a href="./reaction?id=16950"><span>RHEA:16950</span></a>
...                 <span class="icon-arrow-right">myo-inositol + NAD(+) =&gt; scyllo-inosose + H(+) + NADH</span>
...             </div><div>
...                 <a href="./reaction?id=16951"><span>RHEA:16951</span></a>
...                 <span class="icon-arrow-left-1">scyllo-inosose + H(+) + NADH =&gt; myo-inositol + NAD(+)</span>
...             </div>
...         </p>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find('span', class_='icon-arrow-right').find_previous_sibling().get_text()
'RHEA:16950'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly!

Comment: @user310015 So I guess, find_previous_sinbling() in this context works, because the RHEA:ID is also in <span>?

Comment: @fumarat not at all. As you can see "RHEA:ID" is in `<a>` [`find_previous_sibling()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-previous-siblings-and-find-previous-sibling) here returns an element that precedes the element with class `"icon-arrow-right" `